# How to get time of the day, day of the week and month separately from sms query in android

Tags: java, android

I am extracting the date field from the sms table which returns the date as a time stamp, 
but I wish to extract from the time stamp seprately

- time of the day,
- day of the week and
- month of the year

I have read similar questions but none could help.

```
    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
    Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
    String smsDate = finaldate.toString();
    dateTextView.setText(smsDate);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int day= calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

If you want to have the actual string value of month and the day, you can either use a switch to do that

Try the following,

```
String dayAsString = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());

String monthAsString = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Edit:

```
    int hour12 = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR); // 12
    int hour24 = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //24
```

Comment: this returns an integer, but I need to set it to a text view

Comment: textView.setText(String.valueOf(Calendar.MONTH));

Comment: @MichaelPeter Please try my answer

Comment: @Diyoda I tried your edited answer and it worked, but when i tried to get the hour of the day it displayed an empty string

Comment: @MichaelPeter Try this answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do calendar.MONTH, calendar.DAY and so.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Joda Time:

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

```
String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp);
int dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDayOfWeek();
int monthOfYear = dateTime1.getMonthOfYear();
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( myCountOfMillis )                       // Parse a count of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC.
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )                // Instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` object, having adjusted from UTC into a particular time zone.
    .getDayOfWeek()                                           // Extract a `DayOfWeek` enum object.
    .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )  // Or Locale.US, Locale.ITALY, etc. to determine human language and cultural norms in generating a localized string to represent this day-of-week.
```

> lundi

## java.time

Modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Assuming your long integer is a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, instantiate a `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myCountOfMillis ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Apply your desired/expected time zone to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but with a different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now you are in a position to interrogate for the parts of month, day-of-week, and time-of-day.

```
Month month = zdt.getMonth() ;                   // Get a `Month` enum object.
int m = zdt.getMonthValue() ;                    // Get an integer 1-12 for January-December.

DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;             // Get a `DayOfWeek` enum object.
int dowNumber = zdt.getDayOfWeek().getValue() ;  // Get a number for the day-of-week, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per ISO 8601 standard.
String dowName = zdt.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Generate a localized string representing the name of this day-of-week.

LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;               // Get a time-of-day object, without date, without time zone.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).